# Hover effect on comment flag icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comment-flags

For a few weeks now the flag icons on comments don't have an indication when hovering over them. On SO I am rather sure that it was a change in color to red.

Another user suggested that this might be connected to changes in the comment flags to allow them to be retracted again:

> Did you also remove the flag hover effect on purpose, or is that a bug? (guessing that's related to this, as the problem appeared after this was pushed) – Zoe [Aug 15 at 11:42](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351632/let-us-finally-retract-flags-on-comments/388467#comment722035_388467)

Posting this to have it as actual post that can be addressed better than a comment could :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed, comment-flags now show red on hover.